# swagger-ui-express Add JWT token button in UI

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger

Hi there beautiful people,
I have a very basic node.js/typescript application setup with very basic swagger ([swagger-ui-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express)) configurations, which looks like this

```
app.use(
  '/docs',
  swaggerUi.serve,
  swaggerUi.setup(undefined, {
    swaggerOptions: {
      url: '/swagger.json'
    }
  })
);
```

All I want to do is to add option in UI (under the Authorize menu) for copy pasting JWT token, like in the picture below
[image]
I already read hundred of posts about it but non of the suggested configurations worked for me.

So my two questions are

- What to add in configuration?
- Where exactly to add it?

Please help me, it is very frustrating for me that I cannot find an answer on my own to such a simple question :-/

Comment: Config it in your `swagger.json` file.

Comment: cannot do that, swagger.json is being generated "automatically"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `securitySchemes` under `components` like this in your spec:

```
const swaggerSpec = {
  definition: {
    openapi: '3.0.3',
    info: {
      title: packageJson.name,
      version: packageJson.version
    },
    components: {
      "securitySchemes": {
        "Authorization": {
          "type": "apiKey",
          "in": "header",
          "description": "All requests to the API should contain an Authorization header with your API Token",
          "name": "Authorization"
        }
      },

    },
    apis: [
      './dist/**/*.js'
    ]
  }
};

app.use(
  '/docs',
  swaggerUi.serve,
  swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec, {
    swaggerOptions: {
      url: '/swagger.json'
    }
  })
);
```